# Barcoding in Sharepoint

Tags: document-library, records-management, barcodes

I enabled Barcoding on one of the list in Sharepoint by going to Settings> Information Management Policy Settings > .. . There were already some list items in the list and as soon as I enabled barcoding, unique barcodes were assigned to each list item.

Now the other team doesn't want barcodes.. for now. So I disabled barcoding back. I thought disabling barcode would remove the 2 fields Barcode and Barcode Value from the list. But I still see Barcode field when I open a list item. The items still have a barcode. I checked out Content types - both barcode feilds are gone, but when I open views I still have an option to include it in view and it still appears in list items.

How do I get rid of Barcode completely ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Do the fields appear under the Columns list in List Settings? If so, delete them manually from there.

Comment: Thanks guys !

@Rawbert - I indeed checked content types under list settings. Not there either. 

From what I found out in my research is that Barcodes becomes meta data of list once enabled. So when I enabled it , Barcode became meta data of all EXISTING list items. So I think it is like Title of a list item then. You can edit the name of title column, but you cannot delete it. Does that mean I cannot delete barcodes from 200 items I have ? Even if I can't remove it completely, I still don't want Sharepoint to recognize list items with that Barcode value.

Thanks again guys !

Answer (score 1):

You probably checked the *site* content type when you checked the content type. Site content types are *templates* that get stamped on the list when you apply them. So, the thing to check is the *list* content type and remove it from there.

Comment: Also that the list content types are visible in List Settings (obvious as it might sound, still often overlooked).

Comment: @James - Thanks ! Neither Barcode / Barcode value fields show up in column list. But it still shows up when I try to create a view. Strange !

Comment: Turns out those are hidden/sealed, presumably because it's not quite clear that if you disable barcodes for new items you also want to delete them from existing ones. You'll have to write code/powershell to remove those fields forcefully.

Comment: Here is a potential answer. Haven't tried the code yet, don't know how safe it is. http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointadmin/thread/14b69a35-39ba-401b-8549-ee40d3190cb9